# Is the [slowness] tag helpful?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Today, while editing a question, I noticed it had the [slowness](/questions/tagged/slowness) tag. I was tempted to remove this tag as it seems unhelpful, though I wasn't sure. Does this tag provide any value? (Why, if so?) Should we get rid of it?

Comment: A quick glance tells me this is just people complaining in the tags. I suspect I could merge it with [performance] just for the heck of it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Or merge it with [[tag:lag]] (along with [[tag:slowdown]])

Comment: This is a horrible tag :-(

Comment: It does it's best; we have to respect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we should make it a synonym, as BoltClock says in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182849/is-the-slowness-tag-helpful#comment557379_182849).

I have also found some other candidates for synonyms, so this is what I propose:

[slowness](/questions/tagged/slowness) [slowdown](/questions/tagged/slowdown) [lag](/questions/tagged/lag) `->` [performance](/questions/tagged/performance)

[slow](/questions/tagged/slow) is already a synonym of [performance](/questions/tagged/performance), so this tag should be too.